# How to seperate CSS from ThymeLeaf templates

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I am having trouble trying to seperate CSS into it's own file. Right now I have it in the html file. Please help me

I tried creating CSS file and linked it to HTML and expected to work, but it didn't :(

sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsds

Comment: If you find you are forced to write extra filler ("sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsds"), then maybe you can consider [improving your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For example, _show_ us with examples what you mean by "having trouble". What have you tried? What have you researched already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before, I followed this webpage:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-css-js

It has some good examples of how to do this

Comment: It's worth taking a look at [Should posts be self contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18669/should-posts-be-self-contained) and [How to reference material written by others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). As it stands, this answer relies heavily on an external link.